# How to get multiple parameters with same name from a URL in PHP

Tags: php, url, parameters

I have a PHP application that will on occasion have to handle URLs where more than one parameter in the URL will have the same name. Is there an easy way to retrieve all the values for a given key? PHP $_GET returns only the last value.

To make this concrete, my application is an OpenURL resolver, and may get URL parameters like this:

```
ctx_ver=Z39.88-2004
&rft_id=info:oclcnum/1903126
&rft_id=http://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/bibliography/4323
&rft_val_fmt=info:ofi/fmt:kev:mtx:book
&rft.genre=book
&rft.btitle=At last: a Christmas in the West Indies. 
&rft.place=London,
&rft.pub=Macmillan and co.,
&rft.aufirst=Charles
&rft.aulast=Kingsley
&rft.au=Kingsley, Charles,
&rft.pages=1-352
&rft.tpages=352
&rft.date=1871
```

(Yes, I know it's ugly, welcome to my world). Note that the key "rft_id" appears twice:

1. `rft_id=info:oclcnum/1903126`
2. `rft_id=http://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/bibliography/4323`

`$_GET` will return just `http://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/bibliography/4323`, the earlier value (`info:oclcnum/1903126`) having been overwritten.

I'd like to get access to both values. Is this possible in PHP? If not, any thoughts on how to handle this problem?

Comment: For GET requests you can parse `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` yourself and for non-`enctype="multipart/form-data"` POST requests you can parse `file_get_contents("php://input")`. For POST requests with `enctype="multipart/form-data"` the submitted data needs to be modified to include `[]` at the end of the parameter name or the data is lost always. PHP cannot handle that case due brain damaged API to the data!

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Something like:

```
$query  = explode('&', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
$params = array();

foreach( $query as $param )
{
  // prevent notice on explode() if $param has no '='
  if (strpos($param, '=') === false) $param += '=';

  list($name, $value) = explode('=', $param, 2);
  $params[urldecode($name)][] = urldecode($value);
}
```

gives you:

```
array(
  'ctx_ver'     => array('Z39.88-2004'),
  'rft_id'      => array('info:oclcnum/1903126', 'http://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/bibliography/4323'),
  'rft_val_fmt' => array('info:ofi/fmt:kev:mtx:book'),
  'rft.genre'   => array('book'),
  'rft.btitle'  => array('At last: a Christmas in the West Indies.'),
  'rft.place'   => array('London'),
  'rft.pub'     => array('Macmillan and co.'),
  'rft.aufirst' => array('Charles'),
  'rft.aulast'  => array('Kingsley'),
  'rft.au'      => array('Kingsley, Charles'),
  'rft.pages'   => array('1-352'),
  'rft.tpages'  => array('352'),
  'rft.date'    => array('1871')
)
```

Since it's always possible that one URL parameter is repeated, it's better to always have arrays, instead of only for those parameters where you anticipate them.

Comment: if (!array_key_exists($name, $params)) $params[$name] = array();  Is unnecessary, $params[$name][] = $value will instantiate the array if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Is there any way to get all parameter values with identical names in case of POST with file upload?

Comment: @Mikko: What do you mean by "identical names", exactly?

Comment: @Tomalak: sorry, I've missed your response. I mean situation equivalent to GET /foo/bar?id=1&id=2&id=42&file=xyz. The $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] is usable for GET, file_get_contents("php://input") works for POST unless enctype="multipart/form-data" is used for the HTML form. How I can get list of id = array(1,2,42) if I cannot change to origin form and it's using enctype="multipart/form-data"?

Comment: @Mikko I'm don't know how PHP handles such a case. You can write a query string parser if all else fails, it's not difficult. Split on `&`, loop the parts and split them on `=`. Then url-decode the output and save it into variables.

Comment: @Tomalak: I'm already using custom query string parser. The problem is, I cannot get the query string to parse myself if origin form uses enctype="multipart/form-data". Or at least I don't know any way to find the query string to parse.

Comment: @Mikko: Does that mean that `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]` is unavailable if the page was a `multipart/form-data` POST request? I really can't imagine that… o_O Apart from that - are you aware that PHP automagically creates an array if you append `[]` to the parameter names? `/foo/bar?id[]=1&id[]=2&id[]=42&file=xyz`. This works for form fields as well.

Comment: @Tomalak: I'm aware about []-magic but I would really want to have that behaviour without the [] embedded in the origin form's input name (which I cannot always modify at will).

Comment: `list($name, $value) = explode('=', $param, 2);` will have a notice for query param without `=` sign (e.g. `param1=1&params=&param3&param4=4`). you should first check `strpos($param, '=') !== false`

Answer (score 47):

Won't work for you as it looks like you don't control the querystring, but another valid answer: Instead of parse querystring, you could appeand '[]' to the end of the name, then PHP will make an array of the items.

IE:

```
someurl.php?name[]=aaa&name[]=bbb
```

will give you a $_GET looking like:

```
array(0=>'aaa', 1=>'bbb')
```

Comment: Good suggestion, I wouldnt have thought of that
I assumed that the OP didn't have access to change the values

Comment: Note that you can also use numbers (or even strings) in the brackets to pass an associative array. So if you don't control it, don't rely on it being 0-indexed. someurl.php?name[5]=aaa&name[zip]=bbb

Answer (score 10):

I think you'd have to parse `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` manually.

Something like (untested):

```
$query = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$vars = array();
foreach (explode('&', $query) as $pair) {
    list($key, $value) = explode('=', $pair);
    $vars[] = array(urldecode($key), urldecode($value));
}
```

This should give you an array `$vars`:

```
array(
    array('ctx_ver'     => 'Z39.88-2004'),
    array('rft_id'      => 'info:oclcnum/1903126'),
    array('rft_id'      => 'http://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/bibliography/4323'),
    array('rft_val_fmt' => 'info:ofi/fmt:kev:mtx:book'),
    array('rft.genre'   => 'book'),
    array('rft.btitle'  => 'At last: a Christmas in the West Indies.'),
    array('rft.place'   => 'London'),
    array('rft.pub'     => 'Macmillan and co.'),
    array('rft.aufirst' => 'Charles'),
    array('rft.aulast'  => 'Kingsley'),
    array('rft.au'      => 'Kingsley, Charles'),
    array('rft.pages'   => '1-352'),
    array('rft.tpages'  => '352'),
    array('rft.date'    => '1871')
)
```

---

After having seen [Tomalak's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/353379/how-to-get-multiple-parameters-with-same-name-from-a-url-in-php#353437) answer, I like his data format for the resulting array much better, as it makes it possible to access specific keys by their name.

Comment: There's a missing ";" after the second line

$vars = array();

and I need to wrap $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] in html_entity_decode to convert &amp; to &, but once done works a treat. Many thanks.

Answer (score 10):

There's no need to use `explode` workarounds for this. A simple regex can more easily rectify a QUERY_STRING with multiple like-named parameters:

```
// Replace `&x=1&x=2` into `x[]=1&x[]=2`
$qs = preg_replace("/(?<=^|&)(\w+)(?==)/", "$1[]", $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]);
```

Then it's as simple as using [`parse_str`](http://php.net/parse_str):

```
parse_str($qs, $new_GET);
```

Which has the advantage of correctly decoding `%xy` URL escapes right away.

If you just want a single or a few specific parameters extracted as array, then use `(id|name)` instead of `(\w+)` in the regex.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there is no way to get duplicate values using `$_GET` as the second value will overwrite the first

To get around it you could access the raw querystring using `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` and then parse it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Assumed you have a query string like this:

> param1=2549&appname=appName1&appname=appName2&appname=appName3&appname=appName4&appname=appName5&apptype=thetype&idsess=1231324567980147dzeze55sd4&action=myaction

You can do this :

```
public static function getMultipleParameters()
    {
        $query = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
        $vars = array();
        $second = array();
        foreach (explode('&', $query) as $pair) {
            list($key, $value) = explode('=', $pair);
            if('' == trim($value)){
                continue;
            }

            if (array_key_exists($key, $vars)) {
                if (!array_key_exists($key, $second))
                    $second[$key][] .= $vars[$key];
                $second[$key][] = $value;
            } else {
                $vars[$key] = urldecode($value);
            }
        }
        return array_merge($vars, $second);
    }
```

That gives :

```
array (
  'param1' => '2549',
  'appname' => 
      array (
        0 => 'appName1',
        1 => 'appName2',
        2 => 'appName3',
        3 => 'appName4',
        4 => 'appName5',
  ),
  'apptype' => 'thetype',
  'idsess' => '1231324567980147dzeze55sd4',
  'action' => 'myaction',
);
```

Hope that helps ;)

Answer (score 2):

Sharing my version of this function

```
function parse_mstr($query_string,&$query=array()){
    $query = $query? $query: array();
    $params  = explode('&', $query_string);
    foreach( $params as $param ){
        $k = $param;
        $v = '';
        if(strpos($param,'=')){
            list($name, $value) = explode('=', $param);
            $k = rawurldecode($name);
            $v = rawurldecode($value);
        }
        if(array_key_exists($k, $query)){
            if(is_array($query[$k])){
                $query[$k][] = $v;
            }else{
                $query[$k] = array($query[$k],$v);
            }
        }else{
            $query[$k] = $v;
        }
    }
}

// usage
parse_mstr('a=1&a=2&b=3', $arr);

// resulting array
$arr = [
    'a' => ['1', '2'],
    'b' => '3'
]
```