# Multiple HTTP GET parameters with the same identifier

Tags: php, parameters, http-get

Let's say I am getting requests such as:

`http://www.example.com/index.php?id=123&version=3&id=234&version=4`

Is it possible to extract these in a simple way inside my php code? I realize I could get the entire querystring with javascript using window.location.href and handle it manually but I'm looking for something more elegant. The requests can contain any number of version/id pairs but I can assume that the query is well-formed and have no obligation to handle invalid strings.

Comment: Is it possible to change the query string's format? such as `index.php?records[id][]=123&records[version][]=3&records[id][]=234&records[version][]=4` so that you could get them by `$_GET["records"]["id"][0] #= 123` and `$_GET["records"]["version"][0] #= 3`

Comment: While the querystring is constructed by our company's software, the client application has been long since delivered and installed on thousands of computers. The next update of that software can contain changes to the syntax, but since this functionality is related to the automatic updates of the software, it needs to work with the current state of the querystrings.

Comment: This is possible, see this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/353379/how-to-get-multiple-parameters-with-same-name-from-a-url-in-php

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [this comment from the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php#92439), PHP's query string parser will drop duplicate params... so I don't think that PHP is a good fit for what you want to do (except in that it has the same capacity as javascript to get the raw query string, with which you can do whatever you want)

Comment: +1 This seems pretty stupid on the PHP side, I think any other platform supports multivalued http parameters without problems.

Comment: There's a code example for a workaround function in that very comment, thank you.

Comment: PHP does support this. Multivalued querystring variables go into an array and can be accessed from there. No workaround needed. Not a PHP problem.

Comment: @mmundiff You may be right now... my original answer is almost five years old.

Answer (score 28):

If you can change the field name to include `[]`, then PHP will create an array containing all of the matching values:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?id[]=123&version[]=3&id[]=234&version[]=4
```

If you don't have the ability to change the field names, then as you say, you'll have to parse the querystring yourself.

Comment: Shouldn't the first `id{}` changed to `id[]`?

Comment: Can anyone point to a place at http://php.net/manual/en/index.php where that feature is documented?

Comment: There's documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays  There's also discussion of this feature in the top-voted user contributed note on the documentation of $_POST:http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have some control over the request, suffix the name with `[]` and PHP will generate arrays instead of dropping all but one.

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?id[]=123&version[]=3&id[]=234&version[]=4
```

Since they are *pairs* you'll probably want to fix the order they appear in using indexes.

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?id[0]=123&version[0]=3&id[1]=234&version[1]=4
```

Answer (score 1):

Just extract the keys and values of $_GET, use the function as:

```
print_array('$_GET...',$_GET);
```

... and the function code will be:

```
function print_array($title, $arr) {
    echo '<table width="100%" style="padding:10;">';
    echo '<tr><td width="30%" style="text-align:right; background-color:bisque;">key of </td><td style="background-color:bisque;">'.$title.'</td></tr>';
    foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
        echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td style="text-align:right; color:grey;">';
                echo $key;
            echo '</td>';
            echo '<td>';
                echo $value;
            echo '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not as rounded or reliable as methods mentioned above but I use this to remove the need to `[]` in urls without worrying about rewriting.

```
$aQuery = explode("&", $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
$aQueryOutput = array();
foreach ($aQuery as $param) {
    if(!empty($param)){
        $aTemp = explode('=', $param, 2);
        if(isset($aTemp[1]) && $aTemp[1] !== ""){
            list($name, $value) = explode('=', $param, 2);
            $aQueryOutput[ strtolower(urldecode($name)) ][] = urldecode(preg_replace('/[^a-z 0-9\'+-]/i', "", $value));
        }
    }
}
```