# Inserting multiple rows into a MySQL database from a HTML Form

Tags: php, mysql

I want to pull 2 fields from a MySQL database and them use them in 2 hidden form fields along with allowing the user to input data into additional form fields. I am using the following code to do so:

```
$yesterday = date('d/m/Y',strtotime("-1 days"));

$sql="SELECT acct_backup_servers.server_desc, acct_customer.customer from acct_backup_servers, acct_customer
    where acct_backup_servers.cust_act=acct_customer.acct_no ";

$result=mysql_query($sql);

echo '<form action="http://www.bimotech.co.uk/admin/insert_backup_rec/index.php" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<th width="20%" align="left" valign="top">Server</th>
<th width="20%" align="left" valign="top">Customer</th>
<th align="left" valign="top">Date</th>
<th width="25%" align="left" valign="top">Status</th>
<th width="30%" align="left" valign="top">Notes</th>
<th align="left" valign="top"></th>
</tr>';

while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

$server_notes = $rows['server_desc'];

echo "
<input type='hidden' name='server' value='".$rows['server_desc']."'>
<input type='hidden' name='customer' value='".$rows['customer']."'>
<tr>
<td valign='top'>".$rows['server_desc']."</td>
<td valign='top'>".$rows['customer']."</td>
<td valign='top'><input type='text' name='date' size='10' id='datepicker' value='".$yesterday."'></td>

<td valign='top'>
<select name='status'>";
$sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT cat_desc FROM acct_backup_category");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)){

echo "<option value='category'>" . $row['cat_desc'] . "</option>";

}

echo "</select></td>
<td valign='top'><textarea name='notes'></textarea></td>
<td valign='top'><input type='checkbox' name='completed'></td>
</tr>";

}

echo "</table>
    </br>
    <input type='submit'  class='btn' value='Submit'>
    </form>";

mysql_close();
```

I have setup the page that this form post to and echo'd the results but all I am receiving is the last record.  Is there a way that I can get all the results for each row and post them in one go to the database?

EDIT: PHP Echo below.

```
$backup_date = $_POST['date'];
$server_desc = $_POST['server'];
$customer = $_POST['customer'];

echo $backup_date;
echo $server_desc;
echo $customer;
```

I am very much a PHP newbie so appreciate anyones help on this.

Further EDIT:

```
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

foreach($customer as $key => $value) {
    $date = $backup_date[$key];
    $server = $server_desc[$key];
    $customer_id = $value;
    $backup_code = $status[$key];
    $notes_field = $notes[$key];
    $been_checked = $checked[$key];
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO acct_backups (backup_date, server_code, cust_act, backup_code, notes, checked) VALUES ($date, $server, $customer_id, $backup_code, $notes_field, $been_checked)");
}

mysql_close();
```

Thanks,

John

Comment: Not enough info.  How are you echoing the results? I suspect since you have form values with the same name you aren't looking at the array, just one item.  I'm not a php expert but see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980228/multiple-http-get-parameters-with-the-same-identifier with this suggestion: "If you can change the field name to include [], then PHP will create an array containing all of the matching values"

Comment: Hi - Just added further info. I am new to this and finding my way around PHP so would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make hidden input as an array.
Like,

```
<input type='hidden' name='server[]' value='".$rows['server_desc']."'>
<input type='hidden' name='customer[]' value='".$rows['customer']."'>
```

Then print,

print_r($backup_date);

print_r($server_desc);

print_r($customer);

Sample Code:

```
/* MySQL Conncection goes here*/

foreach($customer as $key => $value) {
    $customer_id = $value;
    $date = $backup_date[$key];
    $server = $server_desc[$key];
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_name VALUES($customer_id, $date, $server)");
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for your help. How would I now insert that as new rows into a MySQL Table? Thanks again.

Comment: Tried the code that I have pasted in my original query and it doesn't insert into the DB and I get no error message so tricky to see what's not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Any ideas on what's wrong with my code I appended to my original query?

Comment: use this to know the error of the sql.mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());