# how to loop through get request in php

Tags: php

I have a get request like this

```
http://osxchange.org/displayname.php/?ids=0c313c95-f577-48ac-9175-9f2575684a31&ids=10cfcddb-8a9b-4811-af54-1166b76948fd&ids=1208792e-518f-4c38-94fb-9fc58c61965e&ids=2a2b44c2-12aa-45e6-b680-6534aa76e9d9&ids=2c02eaaa-4a87-4c92-b5d0-57c069d3fc3d&ids=3a47d3bb-2820-4719-a903-e1887e7f6723
```

How do i loop thru all the "ids" in the url. 
I need to loop thru the ids to look up data about them in mysql.
The url may only contain 1 ids in the request or many it is not static amount of ids in the get request.

Comment: You can't. There'll only be one `ids` entry in the `$_GET` input array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple HTTP GET parameters with the same identifier](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3980228) (There's a workaround though. But you need to precise your question, showcase attempts e.g.)

Comment: Explode the querystring into an array, like described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/353379/how-to-get-multiple-parameters-with-same-name-from-a-url-in-php

Comment: i tried `$ids = $_GET['ids'];
foreach($ids as $id) {
    print_r($id);
}` It did not work

Comment: Sorry but if you want us to do the work for you we can't help. Provide the scripts that you've already tried and we can talk.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple HTTP GET parameters with the same identifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980228/multiple-http-get-parameters-with-the-same-identifier)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following script. I hope you will get your desire result.

```
 <?php
    $query  = explode('&', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
    foreach( $query as $param )
    {
      list($name, $value) = explode('=', $param, 2);
      $ids[] = urldecode($value);
    }
    print_r($ids);

    ?>
```

Comment: @saurabh2836 thank you for supporting. please up vote. i would like to know why you ( those who down voted me) did it.