# Slim Framework Duplicated Query Params

Tags: slim

I am using slim framework 3 for my application and in one case, my query params are sent in this pattern

```
test?category=2&category=4&city=433&keywords=
```

The query params category is duplicated. If i use $request->getQueryParams() I get the result as

```
Array
(
    [category] => 4
    [city] => 433
    [keywords] => 
)
```

If i try to use $request->getQuery() the result is

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined method Slim\Http\Request::getQuery() in
```

How can i get category params in an array?

Here is the documentation link i go through https://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/request.html

Answer (score 2):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980228/multiple-http-get-parameters-with-the-same-identifier), PHP dump's query params with the same identifier. You should use the `getQuery()` method on the Uri object inside the request and parse it you'rself:

```
$request->getUri()->getQuery();
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP syntax for array query parameters is `foo[]`. Your example would become:

```
test?category[]=2&category[]=4&city=433&keywords=
```

Which would result:

```
Array
(
    [category] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 4
        )

    [city] => 433
    [keywords] => 
)
```