# Passed arrays lose all but first element

Tags: php, arrays, post, get

I have a strange problem. I recently migrated my application from my local xampp installation to a SUSE Enterprise Server 11 and everything is working but this one thing drives me crazy and I can't find a solution.

When passing arrays either through GET or POST using this syntax:

```
search_dggs.php?latmin[]=52.447529&latmin[]=22&lonmin=17.56&lonmax=22.16
```

I only get the first element of latmin. Mind you that this is only a simple example I tried after the error occurred in other places where the passing of arrays is necessary.

```
print_r($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]);
```

outputs

```
latmin[]=52.447529&latmin[]=22&lonmin=17.56&lonmax=22.16
```

but

```
print_r($_GET);
```

gives

```
Array
(
    [latmin] => Array
        (
            [0] => 52.447529
        )

    [lonmin] => 17.56
    [lonmax] => 22.16
)
```

Exactly the same happens with all POST requests.

I'm using PHP Version 5.3.8.
I guess the problem is some Server configuration but I couldn't find anything about this problem.

Response to comments:

The same happens if I submit any number of variables.

```
parse_str($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]);
print_r($latmin);
```

gives

```
Array
(
    [0] => 52.447529
)
```

php.ini can be found [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10723601/php.ini)

You should be able to see the behaviour in action [here](http://awst.ipf.tuwien.ac.at/test.php?latmin%5B%5D=52.447529&latmin%5B%5D=22&lonmin=23&lonmax=22.16)

The source file of this php file is

```
<?php

    $test="latmin[]=52.447529&latmin[]=22&lonmin=23&lonmax=22.16";
    parse_str($test);
    print_r($latmin);
    phpinfo();

?>
```

Comment: I add the same problem locally and never figured out what caused it (it was with Zend Server 5.5 on windows 7)

Comment: Can you check if your url does not have &amp; instead of &

Comment: what does print_r(parse_str($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"])); give you?

Comment: Your code works fine at my server. Maybe this is 'register_globals' problem? Could you post your php.ini config here?

Comment: I edited the original post to address the comments

Comment: The same with the print_r($_REQUEST)?

Comment: print_r($_REQUEST) gives same output as print_r($_GET)

Comment: Well, you tried to remove your XAMPP totally and install one by one again? Sincerely, has no much to do, i think.

Comment: @cpaulik - a realted question is here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/353379/how-to-get-multiple-parameters-with-same-name-from-a-url-in-php. Maybe that'll help you.

Comment: Post a full PHP file that gives you this error.

Comment: @Incognito I postet a example above as well as a link to it

Comment: Code at the link prints `Array ( [0] => 52.447529 )` every time. even u do not pass any params in the url

Comment: This is because I test the parse_str method which should print a 2 element array, but doesn't. The passed variables are contained at the end of phpinfo(); But maybe this was not very clear.

Answer (score 5):

Well my System Admin did a system update and reboot and the issue is now fixed. No configuration files were changed.

Comment: System updates sometimes include PHP updates and all kinds of other goodies. You might never know what fixed it!

Comment: Configuration was looking good as well in my eyes. You might have been running a PHP version which was buggy.

Answer (score 4):

Tested on my server and it works fine for me:

```
_GET["latmin"]  

Array
(
    [0] => 52.447529
    [1] => 22
)
```

Look in your php.ini in the Data Handling section and see what the values are.  Reset everything to default, restart the webserver and try again.  [PHP.ini Data Handling defaults](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.sect.data-handling)

Comment: Yes I know that the code is right and it also works on my local XAMPP installation, but not on the new Server. If I don't find a solution I will reinstall and hope that this behaviour will go away, but it would be great to know how something like this can happen. The strange thing is that also parse_str gives the wrong output. My php.ini is posted above and I noticed nothing unusual in the data handling section.

Comment: We can isolate that it's not a php.ini problem as I've used your exact php.ini and get the correct results (2 latmins in an array).  Run phpinfo(); and pass your get parameters to the page and tell me what it shows in the _GET section at the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

An example at the [link](http://awst.ipf.tuwien.ac.at/test.php) prints `Array ( [0] => 52.447529 )` every time even no variables were passed. So, seems that you have problem in code that is not linked with this code:
`

```
$test="latmin[]=52.447529&latmin[]=22&lonmin=23&lonmax=22.16";
parse_str($test);
print_r($latmin);
phpinfo();
```

`

Comment: This is because I test the parse_str method which should print a 2 element array, but doesn't. The passed variables are contained at the end of phpinfo(); But maybe this was not very clear.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. maybe its somehow related to that [critical vulnerability bug](http://thexploit.com/sec/critical-php-remote-vulnerability-introduced-in-fix-for-php-hashtable-collision-dos/) ? Does your XAMPP has same PHP version as production? I know there might be similar issues if you post too much data (both in terms of file/post size and param quantity). How about upgrading to 5.3.10 ?

Comment: Hi, Yes my local installation on which it works has the same version as the SUSE Enterprise Server it doesn't work on. So I don't think it is version specific but some strange config problem. I will upgrade or reinstall soon if I don't find a solution. But it would be interesting to get to the bottom of this.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$_REQUEST` instead of `$_GET` and/or `$_POST`

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause of this bug is that someone set "max_input_vars" to 0 or 1 in php.ini.
"max_input_vars" defaults to 1000, and can be overridden in php.ini.

I encountered the same behavior recently with a different cause -- a security patch someone backported to a PHP 5.2 installation partially implemented "max_input_vars", but missed some important bits.  Different cause, same outcome.

Relevant php source code can be found in main/php_variables.c. In php 5.3.8, the rubber was hitting the road in the php_register_variable_ex function.

There's a SAPI "treat_data" hook which php uses when parsing strings like "foo=bar&asdf[]=1&asdf[]=2" -- A different SAPI might have its own implementation of this.