# PHP $_POST array variables are truncated

Tags: php, arrays, forms, post

I am using PHP 5.3.8 with Apache 2.0. I am also using Symfony 2 but that's not where the script is failing. I have a form with array variables:

```html
<form action="/app_dev.php/admin/position/create" method="post">
  <input type="text" id="po_name" name="po[name]" required="required" maxlength="50">
  <input type="text" id="po_role" name="po[role]" required="required" maxlength="20">
</form>
```

Directly in the app_dev.php file (to rule out Symfony from the problem) I do:

```php
echo file_get_contents("php://input"); // outputs: po%5Bname%5D=Developer&po%5Brole%5D=ROLE_USER
var_dump($_POST); // outputs: array(1) { ["po"]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(9) "Developer" } }
die();
```

Basically it keeps only the first variable in the array. If I change the name of the variable from po[role] to ba[role] then $_POST outputs:

```
array(1) {
  ["po"]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(9) "Developer" },
  ["ba"]=> array(1) { ["role"]=> string(9) "ROLE_USER" }
}
```

Typical problems I have found that can cause this issue are due to the following php.ini configuration, I also give you what are my values:

```ini
max_execution_time = 30
max_input_time = 60 
max_input_nesting_level = 64
max_input_vars = 1000
post_max_size = 8M
upload_max_filesize = 2M
memory_limit = 128M
```

These values seems reasonable and I think don't cause the problem, but cannot be 100% sure.

I *do not have suhosin installed* as I've read it can cause similar problems too.

It is also similar to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077969/php-some-post-values-missing-but-are-present-in-php-input) but the solution given would require me to rewrite the HttpFoundation Symfony component.

Also I don't want to have to rewrite the form variable without and array (*e.g.* po[name] to po_name) as the form are automatically generated by Symfony and this seems to be a basic feature that PHP should be able to handle.

Does someone have any idea about this problem ?

PS: this is similar to the problem described in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10026198/passed-arrays-lose-all-but-first-element). Plus the problem happens on the same version of Suse (SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 ).

Comment: Can you try it as a stand-alone script? I am wondering if some other part of your code is modifying `$_POST` since [your result is inconsistent with the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays).

Comment: I've never seen something like this.. `po[name] and po[role]`

Comment: +1 Mr Alien, I haven't either.  I'm assuming you can't do it.  Either way the browser sends the data the same its up to php to process it into an associative array.

Comment: @Mr.Alien It's perfectly valid syntax. There's nothing wrong with using `name="po[name]"` etc. It should work exactly like the question assumes it will work.

Comment: @Mr.Alien Then you simply haven't seen a lot. It works just fine. Usually, that is.

Comment: @Sylvain Can you test what this returns on your setup? http://codepad.org/MWQ8REar

Comment: @deceze really? I just use single name and [] and it returns an array, is that how you shoot an array with it's key?

Comment: @jimp I use app_dev.php as the standalone script. I var_dump($_POST) before any other code is called and then I call die(); So Symfony is not loaded at all when I display the content of $_POST. A friend tried with a standalone script on the same server and that does not work either.

Comment: @deceze interesting... `it returns array(1) { ["po"]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(9) "Developer" } }`

Comment: @Mr.Alien "Shoot"? Anyway, yes, that works. Some frameworks like Cake standardize on `data[ModelName][fieldname]` for all form names.

Comment: @Sylvain Hmm, then PHP's string parsing is apparently borked. I'd create/look for a bug report for that and/or try upgrading to the latest PHP version.

Comment: @deceze shoot kinda execute, and oh, I don't know anything about any framework as I program pure php..no frameworks, anyways thanks for the info :)

Comment: Try accessing the elements as follows: $_POST['po']['role'] and $_POST['po']['name'] and see if you can obtain your values that way.

Comment: did you ever test it on the other servers? just to be sure that it's not because of your local machine configuration ...

Comment: I have few module installed like mbstring but desactivating it, does not help. I also updated the version of pcre to 8.2. I am not sure what is responsible for that function.

Comment: Do you happen to have anything defined for `auto_prepend_file` in your `php.ini` file?

Comment: @Mahdi I tried on another server and everything works fine. It's for sure my server.

Comment: @Sylvain I would say instead of spending your time to debugging like this, just start with a fresh and basic server installation on your server (if it's possible), and then start installing/enabling other modules or components to see which one causes such a weird thing.

Comment: nothing defined in auto_prepend_file, the value is empty, and if unsetting it does not change anything

Comment: it would be nice if you could post a standalone, reproducable test case like in my answer below

Comment: just a guess: What happens if you change the name-values to po[] twice to create a numerically indexed array? Does this work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We finally decided to update our version of PHP to a more recent version (5.3.15) and it works fine now. So this was for sure a problem with this 5.3.8, at least the version we had.

Comment: Yeah, so like I said, "a PHP bug in the version you have" :)

Answer (score 1):

What you're proposing works fine for me. Full test code:

```
<html>
<body>
<pre>
<?php
if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST))
{
        echo file_get_contents("php://input");
        echo "\n\n";
        var_dump($_POST);
}
?>
</pre>
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" id="po_name" name="po[name]">
  <input type="text" id="po_role" name="po[role]">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
</html>
```

Result snippet with 'one' and 'two' values:

```
po%5Bname%5D=one&po%5Brole%5D=two

array(1) {
  ["po"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "one"
    ["role"]=>
    string(3) "two"
  }
}
```

My PHP:

```
PHP Version 5.3.3-7+squeeze14
CGI/FastCGI
Apache/2.2
Suhosin Patch 0.9.9.1
```

No issues here, so it should clearly work. If this test code doesn't work for you, my best bet is a PHP bug in the version you have (or a bug in some seemingly unrelated functionality that hasn't been mentioned anywhere).