# PHP form submit ends after 271 submitted variables

Tags: php, forms, post, submit, php-ini

I got a little problem regarding the submit of multiple forms:

I'm trying to submit a bigger number of `$_POST-variables`, however, my server-side script ends (or just breaks down) after, in total **271** form variables, are submitted.

Trying on localhost, everything works just fine, without any issues. 
Here, in total 771 post variables are submitted.

I've also done a little research so far, trying to figure what kind of variables I could possibly change in order to configure a bigger data range or something similar.

So here's my **server configuration:**

```
max_execution_time  30  30
max_input_nesting_level 64  64
max_input_time  60  60
max_input_vars  1000    1000
memory_limit    256M    256M
post_max_size   8M  8M
```

**localhost configuration**:

```
max_execution_time  30  30
max_file_uploads    20  20
max_input_nesting_level 64  64
max_input_time  60  60
max_input_vars  1000    1000
memory_limit    256M    256M
post_max_size   8M  8M
```

As you can see, it's the same configuration... 
I also have the **suhosin - extension** installed on my server, default configuration. I'm not that familiar with this extension, but using default values should have that impact (i guess :))

**Server-PHP Version: 5.3.9

Local: 5.3.17**

The problem is quite similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12684449/php-post-array-variables-are-truncated?rq=1).

I'm trying to solve the problem for weeks now, if you have any kind of ideas.. it would just be great ;)

thanks :)

UPDATE:

if i'm using this approach ([thanks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077969/php-some-post-values-missing-but-are-present-in-php-input)):

```
$pairs = explode("&", file_get_contents("php://input"));
$vars = array();
foreach ($pairs as $pair) {
    $nv = explode("=", $pair);
    $name = urldecode($nv[0]);
    $value = urldecode($nv[1]);
    $vars[$name] = $value;
}
print_r($vars);
```

i see all form variables and content that i'm displaying before. However, accessing the $_POST variables directly by using

```
isset($_POST['LanguageContentForm']
```

and saving that to a variable doesn't work.. :/

Comment: With `localhost` the `POST` request will transfer quicker so it might not be hitting the the _max_execution_time_. If you lower the _max_execution_time_ on `localhost` to something very small can you reproduce the problem locally? Similarly if you increase the value on the remote server does the problem still remain?

Comment: could this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077969/php-some-post-values-missing-but-are-present-in-php-input

Comment: Can you check apache log file and is there any errors logged?

Comment: This could affect you: http://www.phpclasses.org/blog/post/175-Another-Serious-Security-Bug-on-PHP-539.html Can't yout just update the server PHP version?

Comment: @andyb reducing the value of max_execution_time didn't had any effect... :/

Comment: If you have that many variables to post, could you perhaps enter your data in a csv file, upload it to the server, and then process it from the csv file?  It'd probably be faster than processing a huge form.

Comment: @starshine531 it is a form to translate languages, also splitted into multiple files...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check phpinfo() you can see a var for suhosin.post.max_vars on each machine.

You should be able to change it in .htaccess with something like this:

```
php_value suhosin.post.max_vars 1000
php_value suhosin.request.max_vars 1000
```

Update

Maybe this one too:

```
suhosin.request.max_varname_length

Type: Integer
Default: 64
```

Defines the maximum name length (excluding possible array indicies) of variables that may be registered through the COOKIE, the URL or through a POST request. This setting is also an upper limit for the variable origin specific configuration directives.

Comment: on the remote machine, it is set to a value of 800.. shouldn't that be enough?

Comment: There are a lot of different flags for suhosin. If you're passing arrays instead of straight vars there are limits on those too... here's a good reference: http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/configuration.html

Comment: This one is set to 256 on the server configuration