# PHP Foreach on iCal event

Tags: php, loops, foreach, calendar, icalendar

Can anybody see what is wrong with my code?

I am trying to create a calendar event for every event that is in the $_POST. There should be one calendar for download with several events on it.

So far it will generate a calendar file for download with the last event in the list only. It writes over the old ones.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
 //Set the headers
 header("Content-Type: text/Calendar");
 header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=calendar.ics");

 //Loop through $_POST to get all entries

 foreach ($_POST['listItem'] as $value){

$dave = trim($value);

echo "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\n";
echo "VERSION:2.0\n";
echo "PRODID:www.testMeiCalendar.net\n";
echo "METHOD:REQUEST\n"; // requied by Outlook
echo "BEGIN:VEVENT\n";
echo "DTSTART:".$dave."T230000\n";
echo "DTEND:".$dave."T010000\n";
echo "SUMMARY:This is beautiful\n";
echo "LOCATION:Downtown\n";
echo "DESCRIPTION:Let's get together for New Years Eve\n";
echo "UID:ABCD1234\n";
echo "SEQUENCE:0\n";
echo "DTSTAMP:20101125T112600\n";
echo "END:VEVENT\n";
echo "END:VCALENDAR\n";

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the structure of the $_POST sent to your script I'd say that there is only a single value in listItem and so that's why it does not give output for everything. Have you debugged it to tell if it is only outputting a single value or if it's actually outputting everything and overwriting?

__

The answer at [How to get multiple parameters with same name from a URL in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/353379/how-to-get-multiple-parameters-with-same-name-from-a-url-in-php) from benlumley suggests appending [] to the end of the variable name for GET requests.

> IE:
>
> > someurl.php?name[]=aaa&name[]=bbb
>
> will give you a $_GET looking like:
>
> > array(0=>'aaa', 1=>'bbb')

***EDIT: I think the answer may be as simple as:***

```
foreach($_POST['listItem'] as $key => $value)
```

Comment: Thanks. if i echo out $dave then i get all the values i need. so the foreach is definitely looping through all of them.