# How does google handle two same URL parameters with different values?

Tags: php, get

Just take a look at this url, and you will know what I mean.

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aphpjs.org&q=date
```

And when I go to that url, the search term in google's search bar is `site:phpjs.org date`.

How does Google 'morph' the two parameters together, and how would one do it in PHP?

Comment: Similar question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/353379/how-to-get-multiple-parameters-with-same-name-from-a-url-in-php)

Comment: @lobostome whoops, didn't see that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of encoding the space, Google uses the same `q` variable to accomplish the same thing.

Unfortunately, PHP doesn't have the built-in ability to do this, because successive occurrences of the same query string parameter will overwrite the first one, unless the `[]` suffix is used.

You would need something like this:

```
$params = array();
foreach (explode('&', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) as $param) {
    list($name, $value) = explode('=', $param, 2);
    $params[] = array(urldecode($name) => urldecode($value));
}
```

Contents of `$params`:

```
array(
    array('q' => 'site:phpjs.org'),
    array('q' => 'date'),
);
```

Alternatively, you can change the loop body to this:

```
$params[urldecode($name)][] = urldecode($value);
```

That will change `$params` to:

```
array('q' => array('site:phpjs.org', 'date'));
```

Which will make it easier to just do:

```
join(' ', $params['q']);
// "site:phpjs.org date"
```

Answer (score 0):

It will always use the last variable's value in the provided url. This is more of a standard way, and it isn't just Google that handles it this way. You can try it yourself by creating a page named `index.php` in your root directory. Then access the page via `http://example.com/index.php?q=John&q=Billy`. Inside index.php add this: `<?php echo $_GET['q']; ?>`.

So what happens is that the last value is used, except that google strips the URL and concats the variables' values together. I hope it makes sense!