# Extract variables of same name from URL using php

Tags: php

I am trying to get values using `$_GET` from URL. I've used this method to extract variable values when variable names are different. But now in this case variable names are same.

http://example.com/filter.php?tags=name1&tags=name2&tags=name3

Comment: Can you alter the request? If you do `tags[]=name1&tags[]=name2&tags[]=name3`, PHP will make an array for you.

Comment: Lots of dupes to be found. Please use the search functionality.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980228/multiple-http-get-parameters-with-the-same-identifier?lq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10026198/passed-arrays-lose-all-but-first-element?lq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678918/can-i-have-multiple-get-with-the-same-key-different-values?lq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14734750/how-to-get-multiple-parameters-with-same-name-from-a-url-in-pylons?lq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14576597/how-does-google-handle-two-same-url-parameters-with-different-values?lq=1

Answer (score -1):

You could get the complete get variable with `$_GET` then you have an array that you can browse with

```
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) echo "Key: $key Val: $value";
```

But I don't think to have multiple values with the same name is a good choice. You should better change the way you send your params if it's possible.