# How to get multiple parameters with same name from a URL in Pylons?

Tags: python, url, parameters, pylons

So unfortunately I find myself in the situation where I need to modify an existing Pylons application to handle URLs that provide multiple parameters with the same name. Something like the following...
domain:port/action?c=1&v=3&c=4

Conventionally the parameters are accessed this way...

```
from pylons import request
c = request.params.get("c")
#or
c = request.params["c"]
```

This will return "4" as the value in either case, because ignoring all but the last value seems to be the standard behavior in these situations. What I really need though, is to be able to access both. I tried printing out request.params and get something like this...

```
NestedMultiDict([(u'c', u'1'),(u'v', u'3'),(u'c', u'4')])
```

I haven't found a way to index into it, or access that first value for c.

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/353379/how-to-get-multiple-parameters-with-same-name-from-a-url-in-php) relating to this problem, but solved with PHP:

Something along these lines would work well for me, but maybe some Python code that would fit into Pylons. Has anyone dealt with something like this before?

Comment: Thank you for fixing up the formatting! It didn't turn out the way I had intended obviously...

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, but multiple KEY objects can not exist within the same request? This is against all definitions..

Comment: Are you saying there shouldn't be two parameters with the same name? If that's your question, I agree that best practices would avoid it. It's not strictly forbidden though. For example, try entering this url into your browser (https://www.google.com/search?q=one&q=two). There are two query parameters, so Google combines them both into one. This is more or less what I would like to be able to do.

Comment: Or are you perhaps saying that the dictionary shouldn't be able to contain the "c" key for two different entries? I didn't think they could, but then again I'm not really familiar with a "NestedMultiDict." At the time of posting this I am trying to figure out how they work.

Comment: I was asking/stating that the best practice is to understand that URL is a flat dictionary in some senses and according to the RFC for HTTP1.1 it states (and this is the part i wanted to be correct on if i'm wrong) that the KEY object is just that, key.. and the value of that key should contain multiple options if need be, but instead of doing q=one&q=two it should have been q=[1,2,3,4] arguably. But again, i'd might be wrong and i'm just trying to learn a thing or two without filling your question with my stupid answers :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the docs - http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.3-branch/glossary.html#term-multidict :

> multidict        An ordered dictionary that can have multiple values for each key. Adds the methods getall, getone, mixed, add and dict_of_lists to the normal dictionary interface. See Multidict and pyramid.interfaces.IMultiDict.

So just call:

```
request.params.getall('c')
```

Comment: Perfect answer, and I appreciate the docs as a reference. Thank you so much! +1 and accepted

Answer (score 1):

As an exercise, a rendering in Python of the PHP in the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/353437/1290420) (also includes a dummy parameter to illustrate the need for url decoding):

```
from urlparse import urlparse
from urllib import unquote

url = 'http://www.example.com/action?c=1&v=3&c=4&d=%3A%24%23%40%3D%3F%25%5EQ%5E%24'

url = urlparse(url)

params = url.query.split('&')
params = [ tuple(p.split('=')) for p in params ]
params = [ [unquote(p[0]), unquote(p[1])] for p in params ]

print params

# [['c', '1'], ['v', '3'], ['c', '4'], ['d', ':$#@=?%^Q^$']]
```

Comment: Strictly speaking I don't actually have the url as a string, although I have the whole request which includes the GET and I could parse the url out of that. This approach seems valid as well, but a little bit more complicated in the context of a Pylons application. I'll give it a +1 though, in the hopes that it will help someone with a similar problem.

Comment: Thanks -- I did put it up in the same spirit and the correct answer is of course the one by Jon Clements.