# Get multiple parameters with same name from a URL in PHP

Tags: html, get

This is part of my code where I send  ID to url and I need to get that ID. But problem is that I get something like this

> delete.x=5&delete.y=8&delete=Delete&ID=124&ID=125&ID=126&ID=127&ID=128&ID=129&ID=130&ID=131&ID=132&ID=133&ID=134&ID=135&ID=136

It sends all my IDs from table. But I need to just send one ID, depends which button do I click (delete or publish)

```
<tr>
        <td>125</td>
        <td>Blacksfeets Photos</td>
        <td>di_do@yahoo.com</td>
        <td>2929610140-09 M plava.pdf</td>
        <td>24</td>
        <td>570099</td>
        <td>0</td>

        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
        <input name="delete" type="image" src="images/delete.png" value="Delete"><br>
        <input name="publish" type="image" src="images/publish.gif" value="Publish">
        <input type="hidden" value="125" name="ID">
        </td>

     </tr>          
        <tr>
        <td>126</td>
        <td>TimeSince</td>
        <td>sanlic@windowslive.com</td>
        <td>25189210140-09 M plava.pdf</td>
        <td>24</td>
        <td>614227</td>
        <td>0</td>

        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
        <input name="delete" type="image" src="images/delete.png" value="Delete"><br>
        <input name="publish" type="image" src="images/publish.gif" value="Publish">
        <input type="hidden" value="126" name="ID">
        </td>

     </tr>          
        <tr>
        <td>127</td>
        <td>TimeSince</td>
        <td>saic@windowslive.com</td>
        <td>21813910140-09 M plava.pdf</td>
        <td>24</td>
        <td>966462</td>
        <td>0</td>

        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
        <input name="delete" type="image" src="images/delete.png" value="Delete"><br>
        <input name="publish" type="image" src="images/publish.gif" value="Publish">
        <input type="hidden" value="127" name="ID">
        </td>

     </tr>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get multiple parameters with same name from a URL in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/353379/how-to-get-multiple-parameters-with-same-name-from-a-url-in-php)

Comment: But is it possible to send just one ID not all IDs so I have to to explode. So I know exactly which ID I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have one form for all your buttons. Use one form per ID instead, e.g.

```
<form method="get" action="whatever">
    <input name="delete" type="image" src="images/delete.png" value="Delete"><br>
    <input name="publish" type="image" src="images/publish.gif" value="Publish">
    <input type="hidden" value="127" name="ID">
</form>
```