# PHP - multidimensional array to query string

Tags: php, recursion, multidimensional-array, query-string

Searched for so long but didn't get any **feasible answer**.

**A) Input:**

```
$array = array(
            'order_source' => array('google','facebook'), 
            'order_medium' => 'google-text'
          );
```

**Which looks like:**

```
Array
(
    [order_source] => Array
        (
            [0] => google
            [1] => facebook
        )

    [order_medium] => google-text
)
```

**B) Required output:**

> order_source=google&order_source=facebook&order_medium=google-text

**C) What I've tried  (http://3v4l.org/b3OYo)**:

```
$arr = array('order_source' => array('google','facebook'), 'order_medium' => 'google-text');

function bqs($array, $qs='')
{
    foreach($array as $par => $val)
    {
        if(is_array($val))
        {
            bqs($val, $qs);       
        }
        else
        {
           $qs .= $par.'='.$val.'&';
        }
    }
    return $qs;
}

echo $qss = bqs($arr);
```

**D) What I'm getting:**

> order_medium=google-text&

**Note:** It should also work for any single dimensional array like **`http_build_query()`** works.

Comment: Sorry, but this makes absolutely no sense: `order_source=google&order_source=facebook` You're overwriting the `order_source` GET variable with the second, so you'll not get the first? What would work is: `order_source[]=google&order_source[]=facebook`

Comment: Not sure what you are going to use it for, but because you mention `http_build_query` a note: `order_source=google&order_source=facebook` is not going to work

Comment: I'll explain. It's an Order Management System where the user clicks on multiple links and it acts like Filters in Excel sheets. Somethings like that.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: Yes. I know its gonna overwrite hence I've already written a function which takes whole of the query string as input and gives a multidimensional array as output.

Comment: Why? PHP understands the `order_status[]=google` syntax as array already. Another, probably much simpler option would be to JSON encode your array and pass it as a variable, then `json_decode()` it back to it's array on the server.

Comment: I've used something like this for the conversion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/353379/how-to-get-multiple-parameters-with-same-name-from-a-url-in-php. Now I want a complete reverse of this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I hope that this is what you are looking for, it works with single to n-dimensinal arrays.

```
$walk = function( $item, $key, $parent_key = '' ) use ( &$output, &$walk ) {

    is_array( $item ) 
        ? array_walk( $item, $walk, $key ) 
        : $output[] = http_build_query( array( $parent_key ?: $key => $item ) );

};

array_walk( $array, $walk );

echo implode( '&', $output );  // order_source=google&order_source=facebook&order_medium=google-text
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't really need to do anything special here.

```
$array = array(
    'order_source' => array('google', 'facebook'),
    'order_medium' => 'google-text'
);
$qss = http_build_query($array);
```

On the other side:

```
var_dump($_GET);
```

Result:

```
array(2) {
  ["order_source"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "google"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "facebook"
  }
  ["order_medium"]=>
  string(11) "google-text"
}
```

This really is the best way to send arrays as GET variables.

If you absolutely must have the output as you've defined, this will do it:

```
function bqs($array, $qs = false) {
    $parts = array();
    if ($qs) {
        $parts[] = $qs;
    }
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            foreach ($value as $value2) {
                $parts[] = http_build_query(array($key => $value2));
            }
        } else {
            $parts[] = http_build_query(array($key => $value));
        }
    }
    return join('&', $parts);
}
```

Comment: if you want to send http_build_query result via post then urldecode() the output before doing so; for GET requests its all fine

Answer (score 1):

Although as you found in the comments if you are trying to pass this as `$_GET` you will have override problems, the solution to your problem to get desired results using recursive functions would be:

```
function bqs($array, $qs='',$index = false)
{
    foreach($array as $par => $val)
    {
        if($index)
            $par = $index;

        if(is_array($val))
        {
            $qs = bqs($val, $qs,$par);       
        }
        else
        {
           $qs .= $par.'='.$val.'&';
        }
    }
    return $qs;
}
```

where i am concatinating the `$qs` string if it's an array and passing the index as a reference along with the value if it's an `array()`

**fixed**
After supplying the $index you do not need to concatenate again. See here: http://3v4l.org/QHF5G

Comment: Check the fix without concatenation when it's an array

Comment: it's not safe to simply do key=value, either part may need encoding. That's what http_build_query is for