# How to get the second parameter out of URL (PHP)

Tags: php, variables, url

Can Someone help me.

I have a link like this:

```
http://www.somesite.com/somepage.php?&validation=3545&validation=1431
```

but i want to get the 1431 from the second validation as a variable.
I tried to use this but it didn't work:

```
$Validationcode2 = $_GET['validation=3545&validation'];
```

But i think it doesn't works that way.

Comment: Parameter names should be unique. Do you have control over URL?

Comment: Do you mean this: `http://www.somesite.com/somepage.php?validation=3545&validation=1431` (Removed extra ampersand)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get multiple parameters with same name from a URL in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/353379/how-to-get-multiple-parameters-with-same-name-from-a-url-in-php)

Comment: no, each validation should be unique (validation1=3545&validation2=1431)

Comment: Or use an array `validation[]=3545&validation[]=1431`

Comment: This won't work easily in PHP because you've given two parameters the same identifier. If you give them different names, PHP will do it for you.  This way you must parse the parameters yourself.

Comment: This link is used by a javascript system and there it used a split method, so it can work with 2 identical parameters with 2 values

Answer (score 1):

Use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` to get the entire query string. Then you can apply a regex (try `/[?&]validation=3545&validation=(\d*)/`) to get the value you're looking for.

Regex demo: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/e1L

$_SERVER documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 1):

You'll want the GET parameters to be unique, so don't have two `validation` variables, assuming that was a mistake:

If you know the name you can reference it like:

```
$second_param = $_GET["validation"];
```

If you always want the second variable regardless of name you could do it like this:

```
$key_array = array_keys($_GET);
$second_param = $_GET[$key_array[1]];
```

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely better to use the validation[] construct but the funny thing is that it actually works out to print the second parameter of &validation=1431

```
$url = "http://www.somesite.com/somepage.php?&validation=3545&validation=1431";
$parsed_url = parse_url($url);
$query = $parsed_url['query'];
parse_str($query,$parts);

print_r(array('parts'=>$parts));
```

this prints out

```
Array(
    [parts] => Array(
        [validation] => 1431
    )
)
```