# PHP Get multiple values from GET with same name

Tags: php

I have a PHP page that will be sent (via GET) a variable number of variables with the same name.

i.e.

&color=Blue&color=Green&color=Black etc.

Is there an easy way to iterate through these?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get multiple parameters with same name from a URL in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/353379/how-to-get-multiple-parameters-with-same-name-from-a-url-in-php)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I dont think without using array you cant retrieve data of same name. Example

```
<input type="text" name="color[]" value="blue">
<input type="text" name="color[]" value="green">
<input type="text" name="color[]" value="black">
```

now datas will pass like this

```
?color[]=Blue&color[]=Green&color[]=Black  
$color=$_GET['color'];
print_r($color);

Array
(
    [color] => Array
        (
            [0] => Blue
            [1] => Green
            [2] => Black
        )
)
```

Answer (score 3):

For a variable number of "grouped" values, you can use a query string like this:

`?color[]=Blue&color[]=Green&color[]=Black`

and you'll get an array in your `$_GET`:

```
print_r($_GET);

Array
(
    [color] => Array
        (
            [0] => Blue
            [1] => Green
            [2] => Black
        )
)
```