# How to submit two values without resetting the other submitted ones

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to submit one value but still keep the other one. Because when I press the button for the second one, the value of the first one is overwritten by the second one.

```
 <div>
                <select name="cityId" class="form-control" >
                    <option>Qytetet</option>

                    <?php
                    $query="SELECT * FROM categories_table_city";
                    $sql=mysqli_query($conn, $query);
                    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
                    { ?>

                        <option value="<?= $row['categorySlug']?>" <?php if (isset($_GET['cityId']) && $_GET['cityId'] == $row['categorySlug']){echo "selected";}?>>
                            <?= $row['categoryName'] ?>
                        </option>

                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>

                </select>

                <button type="submit" class="input-group-text btn btn-danger" id="basic-addon2">
                    Perfundo
                </button>
            </div>
            <div>
                <select name="categoryId" id="" class="form-control">
                    <option>Kategorit</option>

                    <?php
                    $query="SELECT * FROM categories_table";
                    $sql=mysqli_query($conn, $query);
                    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
                    { ?>

                        <option value="<?= $row['categorySlug']?>" <?php if (isset($_GET['categoryId']) && $_GET['categoryId'] == $row['categorySlug']){echo "selected";}?>>
                            <?= $row['categoryName'] ?>
                        </option>

                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>

                </select>
                <button type="submit" class="input-group-text btn btn-danger" id="basic-addon2">
                    Perfundo
                </button>
            </div>
```

But I still need a button foreach one.

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Use this style: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era and looks clunky and out of place when used in new code.

Comment: If you have two values with the same `name` you want to keep, call it `name[]`.

Comment: @tadman It's not working with the same name either.

Comment: If you can use different names. If you can't, for whatever reason, the `[]` part is critical. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34781544/php-get-multiple-values-from-get-with-same-name).

Comment: @tadman and where exactly should I use [ ]

Comment: Tip: Try making a static HTML form, no MySQL, no PHP, and experiment with how you can get this to work. Then add the PHP part later once you have a working model.

Comment: You haven't shown the complete form here. Are there multiple `<form>` elements? Is there any form at all?

Comment: @tadman even if do that, I don't think that the problem has to do with PHP, I tried to do that but I still couldn't make it work.

Comment: Check *exactly* what you get in `$_POST` when you submit this form. Your description of the problem leaves a lot of ambiguity as to where this problem exists, and what it actually is.

Comment: @tadman no this is all I want to do categories with <selection>

Comment: This is not for posting data in to a database

Comment: I'm talking about `$_POST` as in *form submission* not as in "database". You **really** need to explain **exactly** what you're trying to do here, and where the problem lies in terms of **specific input or output**. Here is where `var_dump` comes in handy, or a closer examination of your server's logs.

Comment: It looks like you're making two drop downs that have two different `name` attributes. The `<form>` tag, which is very important, is not shown. The result of clicking a button should be to submit at least one of these `<select>` options, perhaps both, presumably via `$_POST` unless you're using a `GET` method form, which is almost always wrong.

Comment: I'm so sorry I don't really know even how to call the problem but, this is more like a category and by selecting this u get the posts sorted by only the categories u choose in the <selection> I don't need this stored or anything

Comment: Oh, so more specifically this translates to "I want a selection in one drop-down to impact other form elements automatically". You may be able to do this client-side if you can download all possible options efficiently and filter them `onchange`, though you may need to resort to AJAX here to pull new lists and re-render parts of the page. It's not a simple problem.

Comment: @tadman look I'm so new to this sometimes I don't know even what you are talking about. But what I am trying to do is basically categorize and show posts by choosing those categories what should I do.

Comment: If you want I can show you all the code for this page maybe you will get it

Comment: That's way too much to get into. These "dynamic forms" can be a huge hassle to set up properly, so if you're in over your head that's understandable. This is where services like [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io) can help. Maybe an hour or two with an expert could give you the code *and knowledge* you need to get this going.