# Get data Checkbox with windows.location.href (PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a checkbox and I need to send IDs with JavaScript using `window.location.href`

this's my function :

```js
function getValues(){
  var test = [];
  var inputs = document.getElementsByName("justtest");
  for (var i = 0; i <inputs.length; i++) {
    var inp=inputs[i];
    if(inp.checked){
     test.push(inp.id);
      }
      }

 if(test.length == 1){
                 alert("Please choose more than 1");
                }
                else {

     window.location.href = "test.php?id="+test;
                }

  }
```

and this my php code :

```html
<?php
 $values = explode(",", $_GET["id"]);
 print_r($values);
?>
```

The problem is I want to division the array and show the IDs in different variables, for examples if my URL Take 2 IDs `compare.php?id=2,5`;

I need to make like this `$var1 = ID1`  `$var2 = ID2`

Comment: You need to have separate identifiers for the query parameters. Or else you should have an ajax call and send data to your php with id being an array

Comment: you are using same reference (Eg : id). Better use array or string

Comment: for the php part you should parse the query string  manually , take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/353379/how-to-get-multiple-parameters-with-same-name-from-a-url-in-php

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I don't need ajax, just I need to send ID's in windows.location

Comment: @Karim I use this `$values = explode(",", $_GET["id"]);` I need to show it ?

Answer (score 0):

If your `test[0]=test1` and `test[1]=test2`

```
window.location.href = "test.php?id[]="+test[0]+"&id[]="+test[1];

$id = $_GET['id'];
print_r($_GET['id']);
```

**Output:**

```
Array ( [0] => test1 [1] => test2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Post your data as an array and read it in php as an array.

```
window.location.href = "test.php?id[]="+test[0]+"&id[]="+test[1];
```

> ?id[]=1&id[]=2 (Best way- PHP reads this into an array)
>
> ?id=1&id=2 (Bad way- PHP will only register last value)

Comment: in the windows location I send data like this `id=2,5` so I need to division it in 2 variables for example

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why you need to split in differents variables, but you can do it using [variable variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Option 1) Creating variables with name based on ID value

```
<?php

// when values is [1, 10, 5]
$values = explode(",", $_GET["id"]);

foreach ($values as $id) {
    $varname = "var{$id}";
    $$varname = $id;
}

echo $var1; // output 1
echo $var10; // output 10
echo $var5; // output 5
```

Option 2) Creating variables with sequential suffix

```
<?php

// when values is [1, 10, 5]
$values = explode(",", $_GET["id"]);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($values); $i++) {
    $id = $values[$i];
    $varname = "var{$i}";
    $$varname = $id;
}

echo $var0; // output 1
echo $var1; // output 10
echo $var2; // output 5
```