# Duplicate Parameter Names

Tags: php, html, url

If I accidentally set a parameter in the url multiple times, I notice my browser uses the last instance:

ie: http://localhost:8080/test.php?tag=1&tag=2&tag=3

Tag would equal 3.

Is this a pretty standard response across browsers, or might some browsers use the first value?

Comment: I think you can use an array for that. The result will be like this: `[1, 2, 3]`.

Comment: I'm not trying to pass an array, just trying to figure which value the browser would use if a parameter was specified multiple times.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get multiple parameters with same name from a URL in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/353379/how-to-get-multiple-parameters-with-same-name-from-a-url-in-php)

Answer (score -1):

Your URL should be like this if you want all parameters

```
http://localhost:8080/test.php?tag[]=1&tag[]=2&tag[]=3
```