# PHP _GET values in an array

Tags: php, get

I have list of items, after selecting them and pressing a submit button
there's kind of a query in the url bar as such :

```
adrese-id=7&food-id=1&food-id=2&food-id=3&food-id=4
```

Trying to get all of the food IDs in an array but no luck so far, tried doing:

```
$ids = $_GET['food-id'];
```

but that just has the last value, which is 4...

How do I get those values in an array?

Comment: Please add the HTML which is generating the request.

Comment: Have your tried `$_GET[]` yet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get multiple parameters with same name from a URL in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/353379/how-to-get-multiple-parameters-with-same-name-from-a-url-in-php)

Comment: Possible [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to name your field to indicate it's an "array". So, instead of `food-id`, append brackets to the end to make it `food-id[]`

For example:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="food-id[]" value="1"> Pizza
<input type="checkbox" name="food-id[]" value="2"> Cheese
<input type="checkbox" name="food-id[]" value="3"> Pepperonis
```

Accessing it in PHP will be the same, `$_GET['food-id']` (but it will be an array this time).

Answer (score 0):

In php the `$_GET` array has `$key => $value` pairs. The 'food-id' in this case is the `$key`.
Because all your values (1,2,3,4) have the same key: 'food-id' the array looks like this:

```
$_GET = [
'food-id' => 1,
'food-id' => 2,
'food-id' => 3,
'food-id' => 4,
]
```

This will always be parsed with the last `$key => $value` pair being used:

```
$_GET = [
'food-id' => 4
]
```

The solution to this is always using unique keys in your arrays.

Answer (score -1):

You really need to provide the HTML fragment that generates the values. However if you look at your GET request the values for food-id are not being submitted as an array which is presumably what you want. Your GET request should look more like:

`adrese-id=7&food-id[]=1&food-id[]=2&food-id[]=3&food-id[]=4`

which should give you a clue as to how your HTML form values should be named.