# How to get multiple values of same param for url

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm building a PHP querying a mongodo database. I need to retreive the value of a param from the url, and there is potentially more than one.

An example url would look like this

http://localhost/api/v1/report-01?type=EE&type=ER

How would I retrieve the two values from `type`.

At the moment I'm only get one, and it's the last one.

```
  if (isset($params["TYPE"]) && in_array($params["TYPE"], ["EE", "ER"])) {
      $matchPipeline["TYPE"] = $params["TYPE"];
      echo "Printing Variables";
      echo $params["TYPE"];
    }
```

The code is only printing `ER`

Answer (score 1):

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/353423/6317430) provides a good suggestion on how to do this. Add [] to the parameter name, so in your case the url might look like:

http://localhost/api/v1/report-01?type[]=EE&type[]=ER

Then PHP will automatically create an array of all the type[] values.

Answer (score 0):

Just add to your link after every param(type) this []

example
http://localhost/api/v1/report-01?type[]=EE&type[]=ER

or follow this

```
     <?php
$params = $_GET;
/*
echo $params['type'][0];
-> ANSWER = EE;
echo $params['type'][1];
-> ANSWER = ER;
*/

if(isset($params['type']) && is_array($params)){
    echo "Printing Variables<br>";
    foreach ($params as $get){
        echo $get[0]."<br>";
        echo $get[1]."<br>";
    }
}
?>
```