# PHP - Get indexed URL query string parameters from URL

Tags: php, query-string

I wonder if someone can help me please. I am sending a webhook from Segment to my back-end. This is the final result of the destination URL including the parameters:

https://example.com/page.php?cid=123456&eventid=965254&trackerid=2523654&amount1=233.55&amount2=156.99&catgory1=clothing&category2=accessories&itemsku1=01235654&itemsku2=525124&quantity1=1&quantity2=3

The standalone parmameters like cid is easy to get, but the indexed query string parameters like category1 and category2 is where I am stuck. I tried this approach [How to get multiple parameters with same name from a URL in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/353379/how-to-get-multiple-parameters-with-same-name-from-a-url-in-php) but it is not really the right solution for my case.

I also have the option of sending the webhook in JSON format, if that would make more sense, but still, not sure how to get the indexed parameters like itemsku1 and itemsku2.

I also forgot to mention that the idexed parameters can change depending on the amounts of products purchased, so I do not know beforehand how many there will be in the URL.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Pass an array like `itemsku[]=012&itemsku[]=345` or  `itemsku[1]=012&itemsku[2]=345`.  Then you'll have a `$_GET['itemsku']` array. How are you building this URL?

Comment: The is is under your url creation, please try to replace $ with & which is coming after cid=123456$eventid=965254

Comment: @ChiragKhatri:  No! Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
<?php

$param_names = [
    'amount',
    'category',
    'itemsku',
    'quantity',
];

$data = [];

foreach ($_GET as $key => $val) {

    foreach ($param_names as $param_name) {

        if (strpos($key, $param_name) === 0) {
            $idx = substr($key, strlen($param_name), 1);

            $data[$idx][$param_name] = $val;
        }
    }

}

var_dump($data);
```

This is the result

```
array (size=2)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'amount' => string '233.55' (length=6)
      'category' => string 'clothing' (length=8)
      'itemsku' => string '01235654' (length=8)
      'quantity' => string '1' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array (size=4)
      'amount' => string '156.99' (length=6)
      'category' => string 'accessories' (length=11)
      'itemsku' => string '525124' (length=6)
      'quantity' => string '3' (length=1)
```

Comment: Thanks @bumperbox. Your approach works like a charm!

Comment: @nawissor just one thing i thought about, it only handles single digit indexes, as it is, $idx = substr($key, strlen($param_name)); if you remove the trailing 1 from substr, it will accept any number

Comment: Good catch @bumperbox and thanks for the advanced warning. I will test it out and let you know, but from the testing I did it does exactly what I was hoping to achieve. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand you correctly, but couldn't you use:

```
$category1 = filter_input(INPUT_GET,"category1",FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$category2 = filter_input(INPUT_GET,"category2",FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$sku1 = filter_input(INPUT_GET,"itemsku1",FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$sku2 = filter_input(INPUT_GET,"itemsku2",FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

And so on... Unless you do not know the exact number of indexed parameters there are, you could use the following, which stores the parameters in an array.

```
$query  = explode('&', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
$params = array();
foreach( $query as $param )
{
  list($name, $value) = explode('=', $param, 2);
  $params[urldecode($name)][] = urldecode($value);
}
```

Say you were to then visit the link https://example.com/page.php?itemsku=test1&itemsku=test2

`$params['itemsku'][0]` would return: `test1`
`$params['itemsku'][1]` would return: `test2`

And to loop through the `itemsku` parameter array, just do:

```
foreach($params['itemsku'] as $sku){
   echo $sku . "\n";
}
```

Would output:

```
test1
test2
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if I understand you correctly, but you can use `parse_url`.  In your case:

```
$url = 'https://example.com/page.php?cid=123456&eventid=965254&trackerid=2523654&amount1=233.55&amount2=156.99&catgory1=clothing&category2=accessories&itemsku1=01235654&itemsku2=525124&quantity1=1&quantity2=3';

$temp_array = [];
parse_str(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $temp_array);
var_dump($temp_array);
```

This will produce an array with all the query parameters.  You can then access each parameter such as:

```
echo $temp_array['cid'];
echo $temp_array['catgory1'];
echo $temp_array['catgory2'];
echo $temp_array['itemsku1'];
echo $temp_array['itemsku2'];
```